# all the Numberformat exception below the one which recently got caught are executed on their own

Tags: java, exception

My programs gets two students name and three subject marks and calculate average of the student.In the middle i got to catch numberFormatexception if mark is other than integer and other two user defined exception.
whenever the numberFormatexception is caught,the other numberformatecxceptions below are caught on their own.

```
import java.util.*;

class ude1 extends Exception
{
    public ude1()
    {
        System.out.println("User defind exception 1 thrown");
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return "NegativeValueException";
    }
}
class ude2 extends Exception
{
    public ude2()
    {
        System.out.println("User defind exception 2 thrown");
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ValueOutofBouundException";
    }
}
class excep6
{
    /* String stud_name;
    int mark1,mark2,mark3;
    excep6(String name,int a,int b,int c)
    {
        stud_name=name;
        mark1=a;
        mark2=b;
        mark3=c;
    }
    public void calculator()
    {
      float avg=0;
      avg=(mark1+mark2+mark3)/3;
      System.out.println("The average of "+stud_name+" is "+avg);

    } */
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a=0,b=0,c=0,l=2;
        String std="";

        while(l>0)
        {
    try{
        System.out.println("enter student name");
        std=in.next();
        System.out.println("enter mark1");

        if(in.hasNextInt())
            a=in.nextInt();
        else
            throw new NumberFormatException();
        if(a<0)
        {
            throw new ude1();
        }
        if(a>100)
        {
            throw new ude2();
        }
    }
    catch(ude1 u1)
        {
            System.out.println(u1.toString());a=0;
        }
    catch(ude2 u2)
        {
            System.out.println(u2.toString());a=0;
        }
    catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {
            System.out.println("NumberFormat Exception");a=0;
        }
        System.out.println("enter mark2");
    try{
        if(in.hasNextInt())
            b=in.nextInt();
        else
            throw new NumberFormatException();
        if(b<0)
        {
            throw new ude1();
        }
        if(b>100)
        {
            throw new ude2();
        }
    }
    catch(ude1 u1)
        {
            System.out.println(u1.toString());b=0;
        }
    catch(ude2 u2)
        {
            System.out.println(u2.toString());b=0;
        }
    catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {
            System.out.println("NumberFormatException Exception");b=0;
        }
        System.out.println("enter mark3");
    try{
        if(in.hasNextInt())
            c=in.nextInt();
        else
            throw new NumberFormatException();
        if(c<0)
        {
            throw new ude1();
        }
        if(c>100)
        {
            throw new ude2();
        }
        }
    catch(ude1 u1)
        {
            System.out.println(u1.toString());c=0;
        }
    catch(ude2 u2)
        {
            System.out.println(u2.toString());c=0;
        }
    catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {
            System.out.println("NumberFormatException Exception");c=0;
        }
        System.out.println("The average of student "+std+" is "+(a+b+c)/3);
        l--;
        }
    }
}
```

I expect

```
enter the name 
sat
enter mark1
i
NumberFormat exception
enter mark2
34
enter mark3
56
the avg is 30
```

rather than

```
enter the name 
sat
enter mark1
i
NumberFormat exception
enter mark2
NumberFormat exception
enter mark3
NumberFormat exception
enter the name
_
```

Comment: Don't write code like this. The two user-defined exceptions and their throws and catches are all completely unnecessary. You detected those conditions: deal with it straight away. You could reduce this to less than  quarter of its length and make it far easier to understand.

Comment: Follow the Java Naming Conventions: class names are written in PascalCade, meaning they start with uppercase. Method names and variable names are written in camelCase.

Answer (score 1):

If you call `hasNextInt()` and it returns `false`, then call it again, it is guaranteed to return `false` again.

The `hasNextInt()` does NOT skip the token that is not an integer.  It leaves in in the scanner so that you can attempt to read it as something else.

In most cases, the correct way to recover from unexpected input (e.g. a non-integer when an integer is expected) is to call `nextLine()` and discard the result.  A `nextLine()` call will *consume* all characters up to and including the next end-of-line.

---

You should also take note of the comments about:

- following style conventions in class names, and
- inappropriate use of custom exceptions.